# Problema con ejemplo de ORACLE javaEE

Tags: java, java-ee, javafx, glassfish

Tengo problema con el servidor de GlassFish, estoy realizando el ejemplo de Oracle para conectar JavaFX con Java-EE. Realmente no conozco nada de JavaEE estoy aprendiendo y no se donde esta el problema:

Código de la aplicación se encuentra [aquí.](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/javafx_con_javaee_tutorial/javafx_javaee7.html)

Respuesta del browser cuando quiero ingresar a:

> localhost:8080/ServerSide/webresources/customer

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Podrias agregar el codigo actual de tu proyecto, y otra pregunta, que version de java y glassfish usas?

Comment: Parece que es un bug de EclipseLink y GlassFish 4.x, como se informa [aquí](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=463169). No es por nada, pero desde que Oracle abandonó soporte para GlassFish, hasta la versión community es un completo asco. Trata de usar [Payara](http://www.payara.fish/) enlo que puedas que es un GlassFish parchado y optimizado y la última versión de [EclipseLink](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.persistence/eclipselink/2.6.3).

Comment: @gugadev deberías poner eso como respuesta (editando un poco para agregar algo de información del enlace)

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro Hace mucho tiempo que ya no toco Java EE y dicho bug ya fue parchado hasta donde tengo entendido. Si gustas la muevo como respuesta pero no creo pueda sintetizar más la respuesta. Saludos.

Comment: @gugadev pues ponlo así sin más y sólo añade que el parche está en el enlace. Lo menos que te vas a llevar es un +1 mío.

Answer (score 1):

> Respuesta extraída a partir de los [comentarios de gugadev](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/14173/problema-con-ejemplo-de-oracle-javaee#comment23450_14173)

Parece que es un bug de EclipseLink y GlassFish 4.x, como se informa [aquí](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=463169). Dicho bug ya fue parchado hasta donde tengo entendido (faltaban unos paquetes que se añadieron al manifest). Puedes encontrar más información sobre el mismo en los comentarios del final del enlace de la información arriba.

Desde que Oracle abandonó soporte para GlassFish, hasta la versión community no llega a ser tan buena como era antes. Trata de usar [Payara](http://www.payara.fish/) en lo que puedas (es un GlassFish parchado y optimizado) y la última versión de [EclipseLink](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.persistence/eclipselink/2.6.3).

Comment: @Mariano Algunos miembros de la comunidad reportaron una serie de preguntas con respuesta en los comentarios, les dejé un mensaje para que movieran los datos, preferiría que fueran los propios usuarios que respondieron, pero no siempre es así.